# Eclipse multiple installs

Tags: icons, uninstall, eclipse

I have an eclipse icon that is not working, that is, it gives me an error when I try to launch eclipse. I could not get the application to work, so I tried to uninstall it, but the icon remained - some of the files were not found and therefore the installation was incomplete (I think). I reinstalled eclipse (cdt), this time in /home/opt, and now it works, but the icon still links to the broken one. The first install didn't work because it was bugged (had installed it via terminal, but google told me it's better to install directly from the site).

Is there any way to get rid of the one that is not working without removing the good one? I mean, if I do `sudo apt-get remove eclipse` will it not affect the installation in the home directory? Or should I just go and delete everything related to eclipse that is not in the home directory?

Fairly new Ubuntu 18.04 user and complete moron when it comes to installations. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not uninstall eclipse you are right. Do not use apt-get if it is just icon related a specific user.

Probably you have a eclipse.desktop file either in /usr/share/applications or in ~/.local/share/applications.

If you delete the file(s) the entry will disappear.

Go to cd ~/.local/share/applications and list icons inside to remove the right one.
If you do not know the correct and the wrong one, you can check the dekstop file to check eclipse directory of th binary with just cat eclipse.desktop command.